# Cat command giving " No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to use this script to create a list of files names (including their path) and have each path separated by a comma so ideally, an output would look like: file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt ...etc. How do I go about this?

```
#!/bin/bash
LEFT=/home/ndevon/USER/SRA/PE/*_1.fastq.gz
for f in $LEFT; do
     cat "${f}," >> /home/ndevon/USER/left_list.txt 
done
```

Comment: Why is there a comma after `${f}`?

Comment: I guess you meant `echo`, not `cat`

Comment: @mustaccio Or better, printf, since echo appends a newline.

Comment: Probably because `/home/ndevon/USER/SRA/PE/*_1.fastq.gz` or `/home/ndevon/USER/left_list.txt` does not exist. I assume it is because the latter one does not exist. Try running `touch /home/ndevon/USER/left_list.txt` before calling cat

Comment: @mustaccio that worked thanks, I'm still a beginner I appreciate it

Comment: @GrayCygnus, that expansion of `$LEFT` is unquoted, so the wildcard gets expanded, and also `>>` creates the file the redirection points to. Even if it didn't succeed in that, you'd get an error from `bash`, not `cat`, since it's the shell that opens the redirections. (you could get `ENOENT` if a directory within the path didn't exist, but not for the file itself)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably

```
echo /home/ndevon/USER/SRA/PE/*_1.fastq.gz | tr ' ' ,
```

which translates spaces to commas. This works as long as your file names don't contain spaces.

Comment: This will work even with spaces in the filenames:
`ls -1 /home/ndevon/USER/SRA/PE/*_1.fastq.gz | tr '\n' ','`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# read the filenames into an array
files=( /home/ndevon/USER/SRA/PE/*_1.fastq.gz )

# print the filenames comma-separated
IFS=,
echo "${files[*]}" > output_file
```